# Overpass: find highways that go below a bridge

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am looking for a overpass turbo query to find 4-lane highways that go below a bridge, similar to [image]

Here is what I have so far

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[lanes=4][highway=motorway]->.major;
way[bridge=yes]->.minor;
node(w.major)(w.minor);
out;
```

But it seems to find only highways sections where the highway itself is temporarily a bridge.
How to fix the query?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
way[highway][bridge]({{bbox}});
nwr(around:0)[highway][lanes=4][!bridge];
out geom;
```

First it searches for highway bridges. Then it searches for 4-lane non-bridge highways in the surroundings.

(based on https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/69069/can-i-find-bridges-over-water-using-overpass/69076)

Comment: Thanks, that already quite close I guess. Here is one case that is not being recognized: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/52.31854/10.50033 and one false positive here: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/52.3133/10.52841 Could that be fixed as well?

Comment: I guess they could get fixed by comparing the level tag. The highway below a bridge must have a level smaller than that of the bridge (while also taking the default level of 0 into account). Unfortunately I'm not sure how to write such a query. A different approach is to search for adjacent ways from the first result set and substract them from the second result set.